# Why does v-show and v-if respond immediately to boolean changes in objects, but not in arrays?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs2

Came across this weird behaviour when developing a dynamic FAQ-page where the answer is displayed after the question is clicked on.

When the boolean that controls the opening/closing of the answer is stored in an object the view is updated instantly and the answer is displayed or hidden instantly. However, when it is stored in a list, the answer isn't displayed or hidden until the view is updated in some other way.

Here's a fiddle displaying the problem https://jsfiddle.net/masterofginseng/ffqt9n4y/6/

The HTML

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="faq">
  <div>This responds immediately</div>
  <hr>
  <div v-for="questionObj in questions1">
    <div style="cursor: pointer;" @click="questionObj.open = !questionObj.open">
      {{ questionObj.question }}
    </div>
    <div style="color: blue;" v-show="questionObj.open">{{ questionObj.answer }}</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div>This doesn't respond until the view is updated in some other way (ex. by clicking on one of the questions above)</div>
  <hr>
  <div v-for="questionarray in questions2">
    <div style="cursor: pointer;" @click="questionarray[2] = !questionarray[2]">
      {{ questionarray[0] }}
    </div>
    <div style="color: blue;" v-show="questionarray[2]">{{ questionarray[1] }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#faq",
  data: {
    questions1: [{
      question: "How big is it?",
      answer: "very big",
      open: false
    }, {
      question: "How small is it?",
      answer: "very small",
      open: false
    }],
    questions2: [
      ["How big is it?", "very big", false],
      ["How small is it?", "very small", false]
    ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to limitations in Javascript, Vue can't detect changes of values in items with this syntax:

```
questionarray[2] = !questionarray[2]
```

See here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

As explained in the link above, you have to use `splice()` instead:

```
questionarray.splice(2, 1, !questionarray[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of [list-rendering caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection)

Try like this:

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="faq">
  <div>This responds immediately</div>
  <hr>
  <div v-for="questionObj in questions1">
    <div style="cursor: pointer;" @click="questionObj.open = !questionObj.open">
      {{ questionObj.question }}
    </div>
    <div style="color: blue;" v-show="questionObj.open">{{ questionObj.answer }}</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div>This doesn't respond until the view is updated in some other way (ex. by clicking on one of the questions above)</div>
  <hr>
  <div v-for="questionarray in questions2">
    <div style="cursor: pointer;" @click="myMethod(questionarray)">
      {{ questionarray[0] }}
    </div>
    <div style="color: blue;" v-show="questionarray[2]">{{ questionarray[1] }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
new Vue({
  el: "#faq",
  data: {
    questions1: [{
      question: "How big is it?",
      answer: "very big",
      open: false
    }, {
      question: "How small is it?",
      answer: "very small",
      open: false
    }],
    questions2: [
      ["How big is it?", "very big", false],
      ["How small is it?", "very small", false]
    ]
  },
  methods:{
      myMethod(questionArray){
        this.$set(questionArray, 2, !questionArray[2]);
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/ffqt9n4y/8/)

Or a less verbose version as Linus borg answered:

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="faq">
  <div>This responds immediately</div>
  <hr>
  <div v-for="questionObj in questions1">
    <div style="cursor: pointer;" @click="questionObj.open = !questionObj.open">
      {{ questionObj.question }}
    </div>
    <div style="color: blue;" v-show="questionObj.open">{{ questionObj.answer }}</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div>This doesn't respond until the view is updated in some other way (ex. by clicking on one of the questions above)</div>
  <hr>
  <div v-for="questionarray in questions2">
    <div style="cursor: pointer;" @click="questionarray.splice(2, 1, !questionarray[2])">
      {{ questionarray[0] }}
    </div>
    <div style="color: blue;" v-show="questionarray[2]">{{ questionarray[1] }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```